# Select subset of elements by comparing them with each other in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to construct a LINQ query that will take a list of elements, and based on a comparison between the elements in the list, select the ones that meet a certain criteria. Like this:

```
var subset = set.SomeLinqQuery((e1,e2) => e1 == e2);
```

`subset` now contains all `e1` of `set` where `e1 == e2`. Any ideas? I originally thought of just having a nested loop, but I realized that there must have been a way to do it in LINQ.

Comment: So you want to find all duplicates within the collection? What type of collection is set? If it's a 'set' it doesn't allow to have duplicates.

Comment: I guess I misnamed it a bit, it's just a List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a method to generate the **unique** pairs of items from the original set. Here’s my implementation of that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an enumeration of tuples containing all unique pairs of distinct
/// elements from the source collection. For example, the input sequence
/// { 1, 2, 3 } yields the pairs [1,2], [1,3] and [2,3] only.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> UniquePairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    return uniquePairsIterator(source);
}
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> uniquePairsIterator<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // Make sure that 'source' is evaluated only once
    IList<T> arr = source as IList<T> ?? source.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Count; j++)
            yield return new Tuple<T, T>(arr[i], arr[j]);
}
```

Now you can easily achieve what you wanted:

```
var results = set.UniquePairs()
                 .Where(pair => pair.Item1 == pair.Item2)
                 .Select(pair => pair.Item1);
```

Comment: @Timwi - I get a compiler error on the `pair.Item` on the third line of the query example.

Comment: @Timwi - Another thing; say that I have a `double` property in the element, and I want `results` to contain the `pair.ItemX` where this property is the highest. How would I do that?

Comment: Ahhh, the needless abstractions we create to hide what is a simple nested loop.  I just don't understand the need to use shiny and new(er) language features when a simple and obvious construct will suffice.

Comment: @Bevin: Come on, you’ll have to do a minimum of thinking of your own. You won’t be able to get all of your code written by other people just by asking. Obviously, it’s `pair => Math.Max(pair.Item1, pair.Item2)`.

Comment: @Ed: Then read a bit about lazy evaluation, for example. Or about aggregates.

Comment: @Ed S.: What is needless about more readable code, which can be applied to any enumerable?

Comment: Well, a simple loop can already be applied to any enumerable.  Lazy evaluation I agree with obviously (and I did give you +1 for this answer), but that wasn't part of the question and I doubt it ever crossed the OP's mind.  I just see so many "I know how to this already but how can I do it with LINQ?" questions that I probably am just a bit jaded.  Personally, I don't think it is more readable than a simple looping construct, not to say that it is hard to understand.  I can glance at a nested loop and it just makes sense, this I would have to think about for a second or two.

Comment: ...So basically, just trollin'. =D

Comment: @Timwi - Yes, I figured out something of my own. Just changed the `pair => pair.Item1` to `pair => (pair.Item1.CurrentPriority > pair.Item2.CurrentPriority ? pair.Item1 : pair.Item2)`.

Comment: @Ed: I assure you that I too am able to read a simple looping construct. Furthermore, I assure you that I *do use* simple looping constructs in cases I find them appropriate. However, I also reserve the right to use *abstractions* in cases I find them appropriate. This is one of them, and LINQ has quite a few others. Many uses of `Max`, `Distinct`, `First` or `Any` would require significantly more “noisy” code... not to mention `OrderBy` or even `GroupBy`. I don’t use these because I find LINQ flashy and exciting, but because they make my code easier to write *and also* easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Use a cross join

```
from e1 in set
from e2 in set
where e1 == e2
select e1
```

This gives you the identity union with the duplicates

You might want something more like this

```
from e1 in set
from e2 in set
where e1 != e2
where e1.key == e2.key
select e1
```

Comment: Do you think you could express that with LINQ methods instead?

Comment: @Bevin, you can use `SelectMany` as in the answer from @Timwi, but I really prefer the readability of the query syntax.

Comment: The edited answer assumes that all the items are distinct. Imagine you have a list of integers and you want a list of all pairs of integers that are the same modulo 5. It may be important to return the pair (47, 47) if and only if the original set contains more than one 47. Your solution would remove duplicate integers from the initial set.